# How to test GrailsPlugin class at project root

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, spock

I am writing a grails plugin.  At one point, there was a service which I wrote spock tests for that existed in the plugin.  This all worked great, however for visibility concerns I moved the methods out of the service and directly into the `GrailsPlugin` class at the root of my plugin (ultimately removing the service class).

The problem is I still want to test these methods, but I cannot seem to find a way to get access to the `GrailsPlugin` class since it is not in a package and it lives at the root of my project.

I am aware that plugins like Grails Shiro use small grails applications as tests off the /test directory.  However that is unnecessary for what I am trying to accomplish.  In a perfect world, I would like to have a spock test for my GrailsPlugin class.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but maybe you can do something like the following in your Spock `Specification`'s `setup` method to create an instance of your plugin class:

```
def gcl = new GroovyClassLoader()
def pluginDir = new File('.')
gcl.addClasspath(pluginDir.canonicalPath)
def pluginClass = gcl.loadClass('QuartzGrailsPlugin')
def plugin = pluginClass.newInstance()
```

Obviously, I took this example from the Quartz plugin. I found it here:

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/blob/master/test/unit/grails/plugins/quartz/QuartzConfigTests.groovy